# Postmark template: dynamic variable with html processed as text instead of html

Tags: node.js, email, templates, postmark

I have a Postmark email template where the dynamic variable contains html. However, it processes that html as plain text.

More concretely, I have the code below. The variable `body` is sent to the email template, however the `<br><br>` is displayed as text instead of that it goes to the next line.

In controller:

```
const body = "Hi...<br><br> Welcome to our a new episode.";
client.sendEmailWithTemplate(
    {
        TemplateAlias: process.env.POSTMARK_TEMPLATE,
        TemplateModel: {
            body: body
        },
        From: from,
        To: email,
    });
```

In Postmark template:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    1. The following includes text with a br break: {{body}}
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    2. This line includes a br break directly in the template: How are you? <br> Anything new?
  </td>
</tr>
```

This results in an email where the br break does work on location 2 but not on location 1. On location 1 `<br> <br>` is displayed as text: "`<br> <br>`".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Postmark support provided the answer:

> We normally escape HTML but you can get around that by using this
> syntax for the variable:
>
> {{{body}}} or {{&body}}
>
> The triple braces or ampersand will let you put HTML into that
> variable when populating your TemplateModel values.

Comment: Do you know if we can use our own HTML code in direct value of key "TextBody"?